# Opening files after return statement in a proc inside a namespace?

Tags: file-io, namespaces, tcl, procedure

I am not able to open a file and write to it from inside a procedure which is inside a namespace. Just wanted to know if TCL allows doing this.

```
namespace eval ::ms {}
proc ::ms::add {a b} {
   return [expr {$a + $b}]
   set fp [open "dummy.txt" w+]
   puts $fp "test\ntest1\ntest2"
   close $fp
} 
puts [::ms::add 10 20]
```

I expected a file named dummy.txt to be present in my current directory after execution of this piece of code.

Comment: The `return [expr $a + $b]` ends the execution of the procedure, so the part where the file would be created is never reached.

Comment: And there is a typo: `proc ::ms::add` should be `proc ::sm::add`.

Comment: The title needs changing since _of course_ we can work with files in procs in namespaces; we do it all the time! It'd be a terrible, pointless restriction if we couldn't. Running code after return is the issue worth talking about so we should make the title about that…

Comment: Donal has answered your question. However, you have to be a bit careful about *which* `open` you invoke: if you define `proc ::sm::open` then when you call open inside the `sm` namespace, then that's what you'll get. This has bitten me before. To be absolutely safe, use `::open`, `::close`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a procedure executes a `return` (without an option that you're not supplying), it stops the procedure executing immediately. Code that comes afterwards in the procedure is simply not executed. To make the file, move the commands that create it and write content into it before the `return`.

```
proc ::ms::add {a b} {
   set fp [open "dummy.txt" w+]
   puts $fp "test\ntest1\ntest2"
   close $fp

   # You should also brace your expressions always
   return [expr {$a + $b}]
}
```

There is however a way to have the file writing code after the `return`. Returning is done internally by throwing a kind of exception (typically caught by the hull of the procedure, which is the same bit of code that prepares and cleans up the stack frame), which can be intercepted. Tcl has two commands that can intercept return exceptions: `catch` and `try`. The latter makes putting code after the `return` easy:

```
proc ::ms::add {a b} {
    try {
        return [expr {$a + $b}]
    } finally {
        set fp [open "dummy.txt" w+]
        puts $fp "test\ntest1\ntest2"
        close $fp
    }
}
```

You *can* do the same with `catch` (which is a bit more of a primitive operation) but it's fiddly and not really recommended.